# Strange padding/margin when using UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I am creating an app that is having a UIWebView which contains an advert. The size of the view is the same as the advert (image) itself. Still, there is a white margin/padding of some kind above and to the left of the image, inside the UIWebView. Check out the linked image:

[image]

Actually, the image is pushed down and to the right due to this padding also.

Any idea how I should remove the white padding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Basically, all browsers add in that whitespace around the edges of the page to be backwards-compatible with like Netscape 1. In the HTML you're loading into the web view, you can use CSS to remove that:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

If you're not loading HTML into your web view, but just the direct URL for an image file, I suggest either a) wrapping that in some basic HTML (head, body, an `img` tag), or b) downloading the image yourself (say with `NSURLConnection`), and displaying it directly in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thanks! I have a HTML-page. I added the style and it look as it should now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 40):

I know this is an old post, but just in case anyone is having the same issues. I was able to fix the same issue by adding the following code into the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.margin='0';document.body.style.padding = '0'";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];
}
```

Look at the first banner with the above code added.  And the bottom one without the code.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As an ammendment to @thenextmillionair's brilliant answer, put the code in:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.margin='0';document.body.style.padding = '0'";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];
}
```

as opposed to `webViewDidFinishLoad`. When the code is in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, you see the `UIWebView` reposition itself after appearing on screen with the padding. By putting it in `webViewDidStartLoad`, you eliminate this ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

Should be used `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
NSString *cssString = @"body { padding:0; margin:0}";
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style);", cssString];
[webView evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];}
```