# UIWebView margin/padding viewing content

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I've been trying to align my embedded YouTube video inside a UIWebView but the margin and padding just won't disappear.

[image]

I tried to get rid of it by using following code:

```
let padding = "document.body.style.margin='0';document.body.style.padding = '0'"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(padding)
```

It's still not aligning correctly. I'm embedding the video using

```
    let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE?playsinline=1\" width=\"\(width)\" height=\"\(height)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

Can someone tell me what could be wrong? I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the `webView` positioning. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442727/strange-padding-margin-when-using-uiwebview) question contains answers to a similar issue but isn't that what I'm doing with JavaScript? If not, How do I add CSS to my HTML string?

Comment: Use safari's developer tools to look and see where the padding/margin is coming from while you have your app running in simulator or on iOS device with app launched from xcode. Your js looks correct to me.